# How to add attributes in xml

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

please tell me,  I have .xml

```
<Param>
<Mercedes/>
<Audi/>
<BMW/>
</Param>
```

I need to add attributes

```
<Param>
<Mercedes>
<Attr Name="Wheels" Value="true">
<Attr Name="Lights" Value=false>  
</Mercedes>
<Audi/>
<BMW/>
</Param>

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("Auto"); 
XmlNodeList el = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Mercedes");
```

I can't using GetElementsByTagName because name="Mercedes" always change.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.  Any string like "Mercedes" can be replace by a variable that is declares as a string.  No reason you can't use GetElementsByTagName.  Just be aware that GetElementsByTagName returen an array and you need to use the first index of the array.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't use `XmlDocument` unless you have good reason to.  Using LINQ to XML, for example:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var mercedes = doc.Descendants("Mercedes").Single();

mercedes.Add(
    new XElement("Attr",
        new XAttribute("Name", "Wheels"),
        new XAttribute("Value", true)
        ),
    new XElement("Attr",
        new XAttribute("Name", "Lights"),
        new XAttribute("Value", false)
        )
    );
```

Or for all cars:

```
foreach (var car in doc.Elements("Param").Elements())
{
    car.Add(
        new XElement("Attr",
            new XAttribute("Name", "Wheels"),
            new XAttribute("Value", true)
            ),
        new XElement("Attr",
            new XAttribute("Name", "Lights"),
            new XAttribute("Value", false)
            )
        );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By using XmlDocument,

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xml);
        XmlNode mercedes = doc.SelectSingleNode("//Mercedes");

        XmlNode attr1 = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "", "Attr", "");
        XmlAttribute name1 = doc.CreateAttribute("Name");
        name1.Value = "Wheels";
        XmlAttribute value1 = doc.CreateAttribute("Value");
        value1.Value = "true";
        attr1.Attributes.Append(name1);
        attr1.Attributes.Append(value1);
        mercedes.AppendChild(attr1);

        XmlNode attr2 = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "", "Attr", "");
        XmlAttribute name2 = doc.CreateAttribute("Name");
        name2.Value = "Lights";
        XmlAttribute value2 = doc.CreateAttribute("Value");
        value2.Value = "false";
        attr2.Attributes.Append(name2);
        attr2.Attributes.Append(value2);
        mercedes.AppendChild(attr2);
```

Comment: I think this is a pretty motivating example as to why you should prefer LINQ to XML if you have the option!.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a new xml file programmatically then try using this:

```
string path = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "LogInUpdater.xml";
    XDocument doc;
                doc = new XDocument(
                                new XElement("LogUpdate",
                                new XElement("Id",
                                    new XAttribute("Id", IdL.Text)),
                                new XElement("Name",
                                    new XAttribute("Name", NameL.Text)),
                                new XElement("Password",
                                    new XAttribute("Password", txtPassword)),
                                new XElement("Department",
                                    new XAttribute("Department", DeptL.Text)),
                                new XElement("Time",
                                    new XAttribute("Time", x.LogTime.ToString())),
                                new XElement("TotalTime",
                                    new XAttribute("TotalTime", x.TotalTime.ToString())),
                                new XElement("Log",
                                    new XAttribute("Log", x.Log.ToString()))));
                SaveLoginInfoToDisk(doc);
```

otherwise if you have already existing xml file and you want to update it, try using this :

```
string path = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "LogInUpdater.xml";
    XDocument  doc;
                doc = XDocument.Load(path);
                XElement ele = new XElement("LogUpdate",
                        new XElement("Id",
                            new XAttribute("Id", IdL.Text)),
                        new XElement("Name",
                            new XAttribute("Name", NameL.Text)),
                        new XElement("Password",
                            new XAttribute("Password", txtPassword.Password.ToString())),
                        new XElement("Department",
                            new XAttribute("Department", DeptL.Text)),
                        new XElement("Time",
                            new XAttribute("Time", x.LogTime.ToString())),
                        new XElement("TotalTime",
                            new XAttribute("TotalTime", x.TotalTime.ToString())),
                        new XElement("Log",
                            new XAttribute("Log", x.Log.ToString())));
                doc.Root.Add(ele);
                SaveLoginInfoToDisk(doc);
```